# How to make comments on Github without being collaborator?

Tags: github

I have a git repo I want users check my code and leave comments but I don't want to add all of them as collaborators. How they can review my code and leave comments in this case?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that whoever can leave GitHub comments on a public GitHub repository.

Comment: There is no such thing as "comments on git". And the question has nothing to do with Git. You are asking about how to use a web site, namely GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've explicitly limited it, anyone who can read your repository can review a pull request or comment on a commit.

> After a pull request is opened, anyone with read access can review and comment on the changes it proposes

> ...

> By default, in public repositories, any user can submit reviews that approve or request changes to a pull request. Organization owners and repository admins can limit who is able to give approving pull request reviews or request changes.

See [About pull request reviews](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/about-pull-request-reviews).